# Balanced Binary Tree

Tags: data-structures

What is the name of the binary tree (or the family of the binary
trees), that is balanced, and has the minimum number of nodes
possible for its height?

Comment: Just to be pedantic... the minimum number of nodes for a tree of height N has N nodes (ie: every node has one child), and isn't balanced. Perhaps you meant "the minimum height for its number of nodes"?

Comment: @Moody does it have to be a search tree?

Comment: @Tordek: The wording in the question is valid. The minimum number of nodes for a balanced binary tree of height 4 is 8, for height 5 is 16, for height 6 is 32,... for height n is 2^(n-1). I'm not sure if this is what Moody wants, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called Fibonacci tree

Answer (score 3):

balanced binary tree

(data structure)

Definition: A [binary tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/binarytree.html) where no [leaf](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/leaf.html) is more than a certain amount farther from the [root](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/root.html) than any other. After inserting or deleting a [node](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/node.html), the tree may rebalanced with "rotations."

Generalization (I am a kind of ...)
[binary tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/binarytree.html).

Specialization (... is a kind of me.)
[AVL tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/avltree.html), [red-black tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/redblack.html), [B-tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/btree.html), [balanced binary search tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/balancedbist.html).

Aggregate child (... is a part of or used in me.)
[left rotation](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/leftrotation.html), [right rotation](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/rightrotatn.html).

See also [BB(α) tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/bbalphatree.html), [height-balanced tree](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/heightBalancedTree.html).

-- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/balancedbitr.html

Answer (score 2):

**[AVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)** is a balanced tree with *log(n)* height (this is the lowest height possible for binary tree).
Another implementation of a similar data structure is [Red Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

Both trees implement all operations in *O(log(n))*.

Answer (score 0):

[AVL Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) is something that you have been looking for.

From Wikipedia:

> In computer science, an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)  is a self-balancing binary search tree, and it is the first such data structure to be invented. In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one; therefore, it is also said to be **height-balanced**. Lookup, insertion, and deletion all take O(log n) time in both the average and worst cases, where n is the number of nodes in the tree prior to the operation. Insertions and deletions may require the tree to be rebalanced by one or more tree rotations.